# Wildcard search not working for path-index

Tags: wildcard, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

Here is the query which gives the desired results:

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search("( ( collectionId: ( &quot;54930050DETB6CP71D38&quot; ) )  )  sort:documentCreationDateDES", 
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">

    <term>
        <empty apply="all-results"/>
        <term-option>unstemmed</term-option>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>

    <additional-query>{cts:directory-query('/dir/subdir01/', "1")}</additional-query>

    <transform-results apply="transformed-result" ns="http://searchgui/search" at="/customResultSet.xqy"/>

    (:
    Constraints or Search Criteria.
    - collectionId
    - creationDate
    :)

    <search:constraint name="collectionId">
        <search:range type="xs:string" facet="false" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
            <search:path-index ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc">
                //cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id
            </search:path-index>
        </search:range>
    </search:constraint>

    <search:constraint name="creationDateRange">
        <search:range type="xs:dateTime" facet="false">
            <search:bucket ge="0" lt="0" name="documentCreationDate">
                Search by Document Creation date / uploaded date
            </search:bucket>
            <search:element ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc" name="documentCreationDate"/>
            <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            <facet-option>item-order</facet-option>
            <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
        </search:range>
    </search:constraint>

    (:
    Sorting options:
    - collectionId
    - creationDate
    :)
    <search:operator name="sort">

        (: Document Collection Id :)
        <search:state name="collectionIdASC">
            <search:sort-order direction="ascending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc">
                    //cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id
                </search:path-index>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>
        <search:state name="collectionIdDES">
            <search:sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc">
                    //cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id
                </search:path-index>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>

        (: Creation Date :)
        <search:state name="documentCreationDateASC">
            <search:sort-order direction="ascending" type="xs:dateTime">
                <search:element ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc" name="documentCreationDate"/>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>
        <search:state name="documentCreationDateDES">
            <search:sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:dateTime">
                <search:element ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc" name="documentCreationDate"/>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>

    </search:operator>
</options>, 1, 100);
```

But when i replace the search-criteria with wild-cards as below, it does not return any results:

```
"( ( collectionId: ( &quot;* *54930050DETB6CP71D38* *&quot; ) )  )  sort:documentCreationDateDES"
```

Though i set the `<term-option>` as `wildcarded` still it does not work, ***any suggestions or pointer as to what i might be missing would help***.

I have tried changing other `term-option` from `sensitive` to `insensitive` and back in different combinations but it does not work, nor does `stemmed` or `unstemmed` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Term-options don't apply to range constraints, only facet-options do. And a facet-option `wildcarded` does not exist. Range constraints are ideal for selecting ranges, e.g. `num GT x AND num LT y`, but not suited for mid-string matches.

I think you'll have to create a word or value constraint for the same path to be able to use wildcards on it. Unfortunately, you can't just create a word or value constraint on a path as specific as you have in your collectionId constraint. You'd have to create a field with that path.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you. Will try and update. Is there some good link where i can read more about this? That would also help.

Comment: Admin guide chapter on Fields: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields Word constraint search option: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_36346

Answer (score 0):

The following description answers the **how**, its a supplement to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781199/468763) by @grtjn.

This is the part which was changed in the query:

```xml
<search:constraint name="collectionId">
    <search:word>
        <search:field name="collectionIdField"/>
        <search:term-option>case-insensitive</search:term-option>
        <search:term-option>unstemmed</search:term-option>
        <search:term-option>wildcarded</search:term-option>
        <search:term-option>punctuation-insensitive</search:term-option>
    </search:word>
</search:constraint>
```

I could use the above in my query because i [created a field](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields) - `collectionIdField` of type - `path`, with path as `//cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id`.

This is the query used for creating the field, this can also be done from the admin-console but i prefer the query way:

```xml
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

(:
  get admin configuration
:)
let $config := admin:get-configuration()

(:
    Specify the database where you want to create this field
:)
let $dbid := xdmp:database("My-Database")

(:
    The field you want to create
:)
let $field-name := "collectionIdField"

(:
    Since you are creating a path-field, specify the path.
    Multiple field-paths can be specified
:)
let $field-paths := (
                      admin:database-field-path("//cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id", xs:double(1.0))
                    )
(:
    Link database-field with field-path
:)
let $fieldspec := admin:database-path-field($field-name, $field-paths)

let $addFieldConfig := admin:database-add-field($config, $dbid, $fieldspec)

(:
    Save the new database-add-field configuration to create the field
:)
return admin:save-configuration($addFieldConfig)
```

So here is my final query which actually worked:

```xml
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

search:search("( ( collectionId: ( &quot;54930050DETB6CP71D38&quot; ) )  )  sort:documentCreationDateDES", 
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">

    <term>
        <empty apply="all-results"/>
        <term-option>unstemmed</term-option>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>

    <additional-query>{cts:directory-query('/dir/subdir01/', "1")}</additional-query>

    <transform-results apply="transformed-result" ns="http://searchgui/search" at="/customResultSet.xqy"/>

    (:
    Constraints or Search Criteria.
    - collectionId
    - creationDate
    :)

    <search:constraint name="collectionId">
        <search:word>
            <search:field name="collectionIdField"/>
            <search:term-option>case-insensitive</search:term-option>
            <search:term-option>unstemmed</search:term-option>
            <search:term-option>wildcarded</search:term-option>
            <search:term-option>punctuation-insensitive</search:term-option>
        </search:word>
    </search:constraint>

    <search:constraint name="creationDateRange">
        <search:range type="xs:dateTime" facet="false">
            <search:bucket ge="0" lt="0" name="documentCreationDate">
                Search by Document Creation date / uploaded date
            </search:bucket>
            <search:element ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc" name="documentCreationDate"/>
            <facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>
            <facet-option>item-order</facet-option>
            <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
        </search:range>
    </search:constraint>

    (:
    Sorting options:
    - collectionId
    - creationDate
    :)
    <search:operator name="sort">

        (: Document Collection Id :)
        <search:state name="collectionIdASC">
            <search:sort-order direction="ascending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc">
                    //cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id
                </search:path-index>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>
        <search:state name="collectionIdDES">
            <search:sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:string">
                <search:path-index ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc">
                    //cd:documentCollections/cd:collection/cd:id
                </search:path-index>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>

        (: Creation Date :)
        <search:state name="documentCreationDateASC">
            <search:sort-order direction="ascending" type="xs:dateTime">
                <search:element ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc" name="documentCreationDate"/>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>
        <search:state name="documentCreationDateDES">
            <search:sort-order direction="descending" type="xs:dateTime">
                <search:element ns="http://any.anyns.com/2013/doc" name="documentCreationDate"/>
            </search:sort-order>
        </search:state>

    </search:operator>
</options>, 1, 100);
```

Field helps with the wildcard and it has its own term-options to be supplied in the `<word>` element as shown above.